# Lots of errors in memtest on one of my memory, can I still use it?

Tags: memory, memtest

I have a RAM stick in my PC that has shown to be full of errors when I run memtest.

Can I still use that memory even though it has errors?

I'm sure it had errors before and the computer is still good and shows no trace of errors.

Comment: You can certainly try before replacing it. You do run risks of losing data and blue screens, but that is entirely up to you. I've seen errors in it before but no major issues for a short while of use while a replacement has been in the mail. But I would plan on replacing it at some point. Unless there is a short, it shouldn't have any adverse effects on other components...

Comment: It could generate files with random errors.  The errors might go undetected.  If Windows is crash free you might be able to use it temporarily but you risk the possibility of either data corruption or errors in the data.

Comment: per stack overflows rules, we're not supposed to provide opinion, so the clinical facts are: a critical component has indicated that it is failing and the component is not user-serviceable.  Replacement is indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If this one stick of RAM consistently shows errors then you should replace it.  Lets put it this way, would you get on an airplane whose flight computers had memory errors, but looked OK otherwise?  I wouldnt.  Its just not worth the risk.  Memory is cheap, so why not replace it?

Comment: It didnt show errors before at all! like theres no trace of failed ram on it. it just so happened that a few nights ago i installed an xp driver on this pc and so i had BSOD. and i cant fresh install the os cause turns out the ram is faulty. BUT ive been using that ram before.

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose you could still use it, but it would be a bad idea. There are many possible problems that could occur when a RAM stick becomes bunk, such as your data becoming corrupted or getting lost, and up to your operating system breaking, in some extreme cases.

It would be much worth the investment of purchasing a replacement, if not upgrading all of the RAM in your computer while your at it. Using bad hardware isn't worth the risk of what possible damage it could cause.